# Using asterisk in pod item as text

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I'm writing my perl documentation in POD format
my problem is, I want to have an item label simply called *

I tried `=item *` , `=item S<*>` , `=item Z<>*` and `=item E<42>`

all approaches are interpreted as bullets, but I want the asterisk interpreted as normal text
any idea, how I can generally solve this problem without adding more text like `=item "*"`?

I'm not sure, if this is helpful, but here is a small example (I abandoned the empty lines):

```
=pod
=head1 HEAD
=over 4
=item a
A
=item *
B
=item c
C
=back
=cut
```

I use **podchecker** to check my documents, before I use pod2text,pod2html,etc.
and it says `=item type mismatch ('definition' vs. 'bullet')`
I didn't said this in first place, because I thought every converter depends on the interpretation of the podchecker

Comment: Pod::Simple based parsers seem to render the `S<>`, `Z<>` and `E<>` variants as `*` rather than `&bull;`. What converter are you using?

Comment: If you don't make to make a bulleted list, don't use something that makes a bulleted list. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay the nicest solution I found so far is the use of `=item S< >*` which produces the output

```
HEAD
    a   A

     *  B

    c   C
```

not exactly what I wanted (the * is a bit off) but anyway

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you show the exact output you are looking for and the output you are getting.

I can get the asterisk to show up in the output of `perldoc` as long as I make it the second `=item`:

```
=head1 OPTIONS

=over 5

=item help

Help me!

=item *

Asterisk

=back

=cut
```

Here is the output I get from `perldoc`:

```
OPTIONS
       help Help me!

       *    Asterisk
```

Here is a pertinent quote from [perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html):

> And perhaps most importantly, keep the items consistent: either use
>   "=item *" for all of them, to produce bullets; or use "=item 1.",
>   "=item 2.", etc., to produce numbered lists; or use "=item foo",
>   "=item bar", etc.--namely, things that look nothing like bullets or
>   numbers.
>
> If you start with bullets or numbers, stick with them, as formatters
>   use the first "=item" type to decide how to format the list.

See also: [Avoid inconsistent POD =over =item indentation](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=800918)

Comment: the way I understand perlpod is, that you mustn't mix text with bullets(asterisks) or numbers. that's what podchecker says, too. however I don't want it to interpret the asterisk as bullet; just mixing them won't help as mentioned in my edit